# Can new Rancher version be used for local cluster only?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, rancher, kubeconfig

I have been working with kubernetes in a staging environment for a couple of month and want to switch to production, I came across a tool called Rancher almost 2 weeks ago and since then am going through their documents.

It was recommended by the developers and also in the community not to use rancher in production kubernete and preferably create a separated cluster for that and add an agent to your main production cluster from that one.

However in the latest stable version, there is actually an option you can tick to use the rancher only for local cluster so this question came to my mind that:

**If the latest stable version of rancher is modified to be deployed on production cluster itself rather than having dedicated cluster? and if there is any security or restarting issues can happen that deletes all the configurations for other components on cluster**

**Note:** on another staging environment I installed on the local clustor an instance of wordpress and ghost and both were working fine.

Comment: in very short i would suggest you `kubeadm`.. [Production-Ready Kubernetes Cluster Creation with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/12/04/production-ready-kubernetes-cluster-creation-with-kubeadm/). You will just have your own cluster, fully accessible and without any dependency to 3rd party. Why do you need Rancher?

Comment: hey, thank you for your suggestion. I mainly want a GUI to see the overall state and deploy stuffs on cluster. previously I used kubectl to deploy everything and see the health of the system like caprover and protainer.io for docker and docker swarm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think the best option for you would be to have fully accessible own cluster and you wont be dependent to rancher cloud solutions. I am not saying Rancher is bad - no. Just If you are talking about PRODUCTION environment - my personal opinion cluster should be own. Sure arguable topic.

What I can mention also here - you can use any of [Useful Interactive Terminal and Graphical UI Tools for Kubernetes](https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2020/04/useful-interactive-terminal-and-graphical-ui-tools-for-kubernetes.html) . for example Octant

> Octant is a browser-based UI aimed at application developers giving
> them visibility into how their application is running. I also think
> this tool can really benefit anyone using K8s, especially if you
> forget the various options to kubectl to inspect your K8s Cluster
> and/or workloads. Octant is also a VMware Open Source project and it
> is supported on Windows, Mac and Linux (including ARM) and runs
> locally on a system that has access to a K8S Cluster. After installing
> Octant, just type octant and it will start listening on localhost:7777
> and you just launch your web browser to access the UI.

Comment: thank you for your response, Octant as far as I remember is more of a preview only (really cool preview but limited to that and you can not apply yamls with it), I am seeking for something in between a PaaS and kubectl which I can use both for deployment and previewing.

Comment: The main reason that I was thinking to put rancher on the same cluster was that rancher base on requirements for rancher 2.4 requires a 8 gb ram minimum which means 40$ only for rancher if I have 2 other clusters one for prod and other for staging each 3 nodes I am talking about around +1500$ per year of basic start which does not worth it for my purpose. I am thinking of going with kubectl and command line to prod as well

Comment: After some further searches and testing @Vitalii I ended up with Octant with a test Kubernetes instance and then once everything was working as I wanted, I moved only tested yml files to staging and prod environment